# Como utilizar corretamente BufferedInputStream?

Tags: java

Estou criando uma aplicação na qual eu preciso ler de um arquivo de vídeo e transmitir pacotes de dados que poderão ser lidos novamente em memória. Estou usando o formato de vídeo Ogg, por ser open source e porque achei mais simples de entender. Eu utilizei o `BufferedInputStream` para ler do arquivo, porém como os primeiros 28 bytes são informações do cabeçalho eu optei por utilizar o método `buffer.read(byte[])` da seguinte forma:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[28];
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/path/video.ogv");
BufferedInputStream buffStream = new BufferedInputStream(in);
buffStream(buffer);
```

Assim, eu posso ler uma sequência de bytes de maneira mais rápida. Ao inspecionar o elemento `buffer` no debug do eclipse, eu notei que valores acima de 128 estão negativos, isso, creio eu se deve ao fato de que o número máximo que consigo representar com 1 byte seja 128. Sei que os valores estão corrompidos pois ao abrir o arquivo no https://hexed.it, eu consigo visualizar o valor correto em hexadecimal. Por exemplo, o valor que corresponde a `B5 = 181(dec)` está como -75. Como posso utilizar este método e contornar essa corrupção dos dados?

Obs.: Utilizar um decodificador de vídeo que já efetua isto de maneira transparente não é uma opção. Faz-se necessário ser desta forma porque estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação distribuída e os pacotes de dados serão destinados a outros computadores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso daí não é corrupção de dados. É uma pegadinha irritante da linguagem Java.

A maioria das linguagens de programação representa um byte como um número de 0 a 255, ou seja um valor sem sinal (unsigned). Por algum motivo, o Java quis ser diferente e decidiu que o byte tem sinal (signed), e portanto, ele tem valores de -128 até 127.

Na forma binária, os valores relativos dos bits no esquema unsigned são 128 (mais significativo), 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2 e 1 (menos significativo). No Java, o primeiro valor é -128 ao invés de 128.

Desta forma, para converter um valor na faixa -128 a 127 para a faixa 0 a 255, você faz isso:

```
public static int tirarSinalDoByte(byte a) {
    return (a + 256) % 256;
}
```

Ou então essa outra implementação (mais eficiente, mas um pouco menos didática):

```
public static int tirarSinalDoByte(byte a) {
    return a & 0xFF;
}
```

Para converter de volta:

```
public static byte formarByte(int a) {
    if (tirarSinalDoByte(a) != a) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return (byte) a;
}
```

Nesta conversão da volta, se você tiver certeza que o valor do `a` está sempre na faixa correta ou quiser desprezar qualquer coisa que não seja os últimos 8 bits caso não esteja, você pode retirar este `if` ou então apenas fazer o cast para `byte` diretamente sem ter que chamar uma função específica para fazer isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: @RodrigoBrito Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, peço que marque-a como aceita/correta ao clicar no ✅ abaixo do número da votação.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Sim. Obrigado pela sugestão. De fato, era exatamente isso que eu havia colocado no método `formarByte`.